# Filter by match like SQL join

Tags: google-sheets

Sheet1

| A1 | B1 | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| username | Name |  |

Sheet2

| A1 | B1 |
| --- | --- |
| username | email |

How can i import the email from sheet2(B1) where username is matching into sheet1 C1?
All my efforts ended with parsing errors.
Thank you

Comment: Look into `=VLOOKUP()`

Answer (score 1):

Try `INDEX()/MATCH()` like-

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Also `VLOOKUP()` will work in this case.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell `C1`:

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(A1:A, Sheet2!A1:B, columns(Sheet2!A1:B), false) ) )`